# A field for the curious

Tags: riddle, poetry, limerick

> As is, I am a field for the curious;
>   Study me well to be naturally serious;
>   But cut my first and my last,
>   And scramble me fast;
>   Now I'm a home with warmth quite mysterious

What am I?

Hope you enjoy my first riddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are:

> **BIOLOGY**

*As is, I am a field for the curious;*
*Study me well to be naturally serious;*

> Biology is a *field* of *study* concerning the *natural* world.

*But cut my first and my last,*
*And scramble me fast;*
*Now I'm a home with warmth quite mysterious*

> Remove its first and last letters (B and Y) and you are left with 'IOLOG'. Anagram ('scramble') this and you can make **IGLOO** - a house made of blocks of freezing cold ice, something which (in theory anyway) truly is a *mystery* how it can be *warm* enough to live in!

Comment: Spot on. Well done!

Comment: @anodyne Thanks :) Neat first riddle - welcome to Puzzling!